# How to execute this Go binary?

Tags: go

I am told to build a go binary and execute it like this.

```
go build hello-world.go
$ ls
hello-world hello-world.go

./hello-world
hello world
```

So `go build hello-world.go` takes the human-readable `hello-world.go` file and creates a binary file.

My two questions are:

1. Typically, what are the advantages of compiled code and a file that is directly executable? Is it that it's NOT dependent on your OSX or any other dependencies? How come?
2. Why does `./hello-world` execute the created binary.

Comment: Your first question has been debated for decades, and will probably continue to be debated for millennia longer. There's no possible way to answer it in a format short enough for SO.  And your second question is off-topic here, it's "How to use a computer 101." Maybe Super User would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There are many discussions about compiled languages (such as Golang) vs interpreted languages (such as Ruby) but generally, a compiled language is faster because the compilation phase optimizes the code and because the target machine can natively run the program without the need to use an interpreter (extra layer).
2. All binaries are portable between the same OS and architecture. Meaning if you compile your Golang application on a 64-bits Linux architecture, you won't be able to run it on a 32-bits Linux architecture.
3. That's the standard way to execute binaries on Linux and Unix based systems. You need the `./` prefix if the binary is not in your `$PATH`

Comment: "but basically, a compiled language is faster" --- that's misleading and not 100% correct. Implement a recursive algorithm and see how "interpreted" nodejs outperforms compiled go. With JIT'ted languages the performance point is not so obvious for compiled/interpreted languages. I'd remove that item entirely.

Comment: Okay let me rephrase and edit to say that they are generally faster instead of "basically"

Comment: "interpreted" languages also optimise in runtime. And some languages, even though are compiled - do some additional optimisations in runtime on target platform: jvm, .net. The whole item #1 is seriously misleading.

Comment: "All binaries are portable between the same OS and architecture" --- does not go by default depend on the libc?

Comment: Yes interpreted languages can sometimes match or surpass the performances of compiled languages but it does not come for free, it could be tricky and it is generally not the case.
The person that asked the question is just getting started with compiled languages and I assumed he just wanted an overview about how it works. I gave him a lead and he could pursue it if that's relevant to his interests.
Getting down to the nitty-gritty details at this stage of his learning seems premature. But if he tells me otherwise, I'll remove my answer and you'll be free to give him a lengthy explanation

Comment: Question #1 should not be answered in this format. It's impossible to provide a satisfactory answer without writing pages or volumes.

Comment: I think you really have to consider your audience when answering a question before drowning the reader under a wall of text.
It's his first time ever compiling and running a binary, why do you think it is necessary to write "pages"?

Answer (score 0):

The reason  ./hello-world executed the created binary, is based on the concept of shell scripts. Think of bash, every bash file as `#!/bin/bash` to indicate thats its a shell script executable by the shell engine. Making this file executable by permissions, allows the file to be executed with, .`/file.sh`, because the interpreter gets triggered. Go in this case, is configured to act the same way. Brian Kernighan helped created UNIX, he was also on the Golang team, therefore the concept of file execution was baked in architecturally.

The advantages of compiled code, enables static analysis at runtime, Go is a strongly type langauge. This is because compiled code allows the possibility of numerous optimizations.